# Flash Builder 4.5 Standard License in 4.7

Tags: flash-builder

I have Flash Buider 4.5 Standard licence, and I would like to know if I can use my serial number with the newest version of FB (4.7)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per Adobe Flash Builder product page:

[How do I get Flash Builder 4.7 if I already have Flash Builder 4.5?](http://www.adobe.com/products/flash-builder/faq.html#)

> Existing Flash Builder 4.5 customers will not be prompted to upgrade
>   automatically. Flash Builder 4.5 customers can download the trial
>   version of Flash Builder 4.7 and [request a Flash Builder 4.7 serial key.](https://adobeformscentral.com/?f=aqd5Yq%2aONlcAvnasuWDB8w#)
>
> Flash Builder 4.7 is a complimentary update from version 4.5.

Historically premium versions of Flash Builder and AIR for iOS could be installed as a complimentary update.  With Creative Suite, awkwardly uninstalling the old version then installing the new product as a trial to enable the Adobe Application Manager to register the license.  As a standalone product, I believe Flash Builder 4.6 accepted a Flash Builder 4.5 serial key.

With Flash Builder 4.7, you need to request a serial key.